# Can "Magisk" hide bootloader status?

Tags: rooting, bootloader, magisk, safety-net

I am planning to flash Lineage OS 14.1 on my Lenovo p1ma40 to give it a new life.

But I often have to do various payment and transactions using banking apps. As you might know , these apps check for safetynet status. But if I unlock bootloader to flash custom ROM, then the safety net status will be definitely tripped.

My question is:

I learnt that Magisk can hide root status.But if I unlock bootloader then will it be able to hide bootloader status and ensure that safety net doesn't gets tripped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** **NO**
It cannot hide. Developer of Magisk [says in his tweet, after the latest Google update](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1237830559365136384?s=20)

> Q6: Is MagiskHide meaningless now?
>
> A6: It depends on your expectation. MagiskHide is still effective to hide anything in userspace, but is no longer capable of spoofing bootloader/verified boot status.

To put it simply, we can still hide "root", but **not the bootloader status.**

(Emphasis added)

For more details see this [XDA blog](https://www.xda-developers.com/magisk-no-longer-hide-bootloader-unlock-status/) shared by Robert (thanks)

Also see [Magisk will fail Safety-Net hereafter. Why?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221976/131553)

Answer below is not pertinent, but retained for context

---

Safety-Net Vs Magisk is a typical cat and mouse game. But thankfully, most of the time Magisk is one step ahead. So, to answer your title **yes, most of the time but not always**

Safety Net being tripped is not just because of boot loader being unlocked. There is more to it. From [Magisk and MagiskHide Installation and Troubleshooting guide](https://didgeridoohan.com/magisk/MagiskHide#hn_What_triggers_SafetyNet) by XDA developer didgeridoohan's excellent guide

> **What triggers SafetyNet?**
>
> There are two parts to the SafetyNet check, CTS Profile and Basic Integrity.
>
> Examples of when ctsProfileMatch will report as false (failed):
>
> - Uncertified device (the manufacturer haven't applied for Google certification)
> - Unlocked bootloader
> - Custom ROM
> - Signs of system integrity compromise (rooting, etc)
> - Signs of other attacks (Xposed, EdXposed, etc)
>
> Examples of when basicIntegrity will report as false (failed):
>
> - Signs of system integrity compromise (rooting, etc)
> - Signs of other attacks (Xposed, EdXposed, etc)@

@ EdXposed does *not* trip safety net. Guide has not been updated

This is where Magisk comes to rescue

> **Magisk can hide**
>
> - Magisk and most modules (it depends on what the module does).
>
> *MagiskSU
>
> - Unlocked bootloader.
> - Permissive SELinux (most of the time. There have been reports that a permissive SELinux triggers SafetyNet even with MagiskHide enabled).
> - Some prop values (see "Sensitive props").
> - The Magisk Manager (separate option in the Manager settings).

Magisk has an option of Magisk Hide. You need to select your banking and any other apps to prevent them from seeing root. Also from Magisk Manager, hide the manager to prevent apps detecting root.

**Note:** Some banking apps may detect root despite passing safety net. Refer to the guide for help to fix such situations. Ver 20.1 of Magisk has sophisticated techniques to prevent this, so such incidents should be rare

Magisk itself allows you to verify your safety net status as shown

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

Also see [What Magisk can't hide](https://didgeridoohan.com/magisk/MagiskHide#) for more information

**Caution :** It's best to keep  Magisk and yourself updated with [Magisk Github](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/issues) developments so that you minimize the risk
(and your device threads on XDA) . I have been using Magisk and EdXposed on Android 9 and 10 but never faced the issue of safteynet being tripped YMMV

Another useful resource is [Magisk Documentation](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/) by topjohnwu, developer of Magisk

Comment: XDA has a very nice blog entry on this topic: https://www.xda-developers.com/magisk-no-longer-hide-bootloader-unlock-status/

Comment: @Robert Thanks for inputs. That clears up some things for sure! Will add in answer with credits