# correct fingerprint for Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 10 to pass ctsProfile check in SafetyNet

Tags: samsung, root-access, android-10, magisk, safety-net

I have a Samsung SM-G973FZGGITV (European Exynos version with Italian csc) upgraded to the stock version of Samsung Android Q. My current fingerprint is

```
samsung/beyond1lteeea/beyond1:10/QP1A.190711.020/G973FXXU7CTF1:user/release-keys
```

and the fingerprint I extracted from the vendor partition is

```
samsung/beyond1ltexx/beyond1:10/QP1A.190711.020/G973FXXU7CTF1:user/release-keys
```

now when I set one of these fingerprints trough the MagiskHide props config module the ctsProfile check still fails, the basicIntegrety check passes so there is hope.

Can someone with the same phone upgraded to stock Android 10 version **pass me the fingerprint** of his phone software **when passing the ctsProfile check**?

You would be my hero, I tried both listed fingerprints and have no idea why the ctsProfile does not pass.

[I followed this guide to try to pass SafetyNet](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magiskhide-props-config-t3789228)

[MagiskHide props module manual](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/MagiskHidePropsConf/blob/master/README.md#finding-a-certified-fingerprint)

Comment: See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221976/magisk-will-fail-safety-net-hereafter-why/226340#226340) why SafetyNet is failing

Comment: @beeshyams very interesting information, thanks. but from what I've read in the answer this "hardware backed" safetynet check is not yet implemented. So my ctsProfile should be able to pass if I put the right fingerprint and release date in the props. Or am I wrong here and is it totally over with MagiskHide?

Comment: It's already implemented for latest devices and not for some old devices , see the last screen shot in the answer, which shows that. IMO, game over unless your device is an exception. I may be wrong but that's my inference. Try installing canary Magisk and checking