# SafetyNet vs MagiskHide: what's the status now in mid 2020?

Tags: rooting, bootloader, google-play-services, magisk, safety-net

As widely reported on different sites, and also discussed on this site ([here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221976/magisk-will-fail-safety-net-hereafter-why/225510#225510) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220108/can-magisk-hide-bootloader-status?noredirect=1&lq=1)), earlier this year, Google made changes to SafetyNet so that it could detect bootloader/verified boot status even with MagiskHide enabled. The developer of Magisk, John Wu, at that time tweeted that because Google was using the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE), its check on bootloader status could not be defeated. For example, he wrote:

> this new update utilizes hardware-based key attestation. It will send an unmodified keystore certificate to SafetyNet servers, verify its legitimacy, and check certificate extension data to know whether your device have verified boot enabled (bootloader status)
>
> Unless there is serious implementation bugs in your ARM TrustZone (or security co-processor like Google's Titan M), you cannot break the cryptography.

He basically concluded:

> Let's face it. Fun is over guys.

Yet, on March 14, John Wu tweeted:

> So apparently CTS is just passing again out of nowhere? Maybe Google is still testing things out?
>
> I'm over it anyways. Google is apparently willing to use key attestation for detection. Since MagiskHide is still there, people can still always use it as usual.

And another [tweet](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1245956080779198464) from him on April 3 that I didn't quite understand:

> THE BIG GOOGLE HAMMER IS BACK!
> Say bye bye to SafetyNet, we'll (not) miss you...

Did that mean Google would somehow be removing SafetyNet, or at least not utilizing its capabilities to detect bootloader status?

So there was some doubt beginning to surface in mid March. In my own test in late May 2020, with MagiskHide not enabled, SafetyNet failed, but with MagiskHide enabled and targetting my test app, SafetyNet passed, meaning that MagishHide could still defeat SafetyNet. The test was run on a Pixel 3 with android 10.

So, Google may have the capability to detect MagiskHide, and it was working out in the field with real devices, but they have somehow stopped doing that? Does anyone know what is going on with SafetyNet? Was the feature temporarily reverted? Will it be coming back to SafetyNet, and if so, when?

Comment: It is subjective (related to device and OS), nothing can be said with any certainty. See various forums on XDA and your answer depends on what you read

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if there are any indications about what Google is thinking? Or is it just people speculating about what Google is doing?

Comment: it's all speculation - no one knows

Comment: Thanks, hopefully if somebody knows, they could help to write an answer here.

Comment: How SafetyNet works internally, what parts are (and will be) enabled/disabled plus what code is used in the future can only be answered by the Google engineers that develop SafetyNet. As most likely writing such internal information into a public system like Stackexchange violates the company rules I would not expect an answer. And other answers from non-Google folks are just personal opinions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magisk will fail Safety-Net hereafter. Why?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221976/magisk-will-fail-safety-net-hereafter-why)

Comment: @jkmartindale Thanks, but I've already referenced that question, which was asked earlier, when it was assumed that magisk would fail SafetyNet checks "hereafter". However, since mid March, the situation has changed, and that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, good point, but I'm thinking if we don't ask, we wouldn't know. Maybe some developer advocate from Google, for example, may be perfectly happy to answer such questions on public forums, if the reasons are not confidential and they want to get more people using SafetyNet, etc.? Or maybe Google did announce something related to this but some of us missed it, then hopefully somebody else who knows about it might point us to such an announcement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(29 June 2020) It looks like Google is just being cautious, and preparing a new field in the SafetyNet response.

According to [the SafetyNet API Clients Team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/safetynet-api-clients/lpDXBNeV7Fg)

> We have started rolling out a new feature that will provide developers with insight into the types of signals/measurements that have contributed to each individual SafetyNet Attestation API response.
>
> Our JWS responses now have a new optional field named evaluationType.
> The value of this field will be a list of comma-separated string tokens, where each token represents an enum-like value.
>
> Currently, the following string tokens may be indicated::
>
> - BASIC  - When we use typical signals and measurements along with reference data during our evaluation.
> - HARDWARE_BACKED - When we use the available hardware-backed security features of the remote device (e.g. hardware-backed key attestation) to influence our evaluation.
>
> Examples of field values that you may expect:
>
> - {“evaluationType”: “BASIC”}
> - {“evaluationType”: “BASIC,HARDWARE_BACKED”}
>
> We’re currently evaluating and adjusting the eligibility criteria for devices where we will rely on hardware-backed security features. So please do not use the presence or value of this field as a signal by itself (for now).
>
> Note that this feature has not been officially documented yet. Presently, we’re only communicating it to this announcement-list to collect feedback.
>
> We encourage you to use our feedback form based on your experience with this new feature as well as the overall service.
>
> Thanks & Regards,
> SafetyNet API Clients team

So once testing for this new feature is completed, it looks like hardware-backed key attestation will be put in place. Which means, from then on, SafetyNet would be able to detect bootloader/verified boot status even with MagiskHide enabled.

### John Wu is still fighting back

(updated on 29 June 2020)

John Wu is trying to persuade Google to not blindly apply SafetyNet hardware-backed attestation across the board. He tweeted:

> I advocate
> @AndroidDev
> to restrict hardware-backed SafetyNet evaluation to "real" security sensitive apps. Developers should go through an application process to qualify this level of API access. It is ridiculous for McDonalds to refuse to run on a bootloader unlocked device.

Meanwhile, it appears that the SafetyNet checks will still fail even if the bootloader is re-locked, as we see [here, tweeted 3 July 2020](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1278849731305672705)

> Bad news: it is confirmed that for those who wants to re-lock their bootloader with self signed images (possible on Pixel devices), SafetyNet with HARDWARE-BACKED evaluation will still *NOT* pass CTS check.

**(Updated on 13 Dec 2020)** John Wu [now tweets](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1337860804788436993)

> Let me get this out of the way: since I have a full time job now, I don't have much time for Magisk; I need prioritization. HW based evaluation is impractical to "hack" (except tricks to make it fallback to basic), and I lost all interest in improving the current way of hiding.

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, I had already posted this URL https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/safetynet-api-clients/lpDXBNeV7Fg earlier today, so it is clear what is happening.

Comment: @beeshyams Anyway, it is good to know ; so more apps may be using SafetyNet in the future. Do you think that would be "better" alternatives for rooting in that case?

Comment: I feel it is for the better. Make a choice - you want root or secure apps. You can't have both //Better alternatives are possible, we had many before Su, root kit apps and now Magisk. Once John Wu quits development, one may find new methods. I feel Magisk is the best we ever had and likely to be in a while. For me, I will put off upgrading to 11 till the picture is clear (I don't need any SafetyNet) but use banking apps that don't like root. If root can be hidden as John says, I am good :)

Comment: @beeshyams Or one phone for root, one for banking/secure apps :-). Yes, I agree with you, Magisk was very skillfully done.